# pandas dataframe groupby: sum/count of only positive numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe ('frame') on which I want to aggregate by Country and Date:

```
aggregated=pd.DataFrame(frame.groupby(['Country','Date']).CaseID.count())

aggregated["Total duration"]=frame.groupby(['Country','Date']).Hours.sum()

aggregated["Mean duration"]=frame.groupby(['Country','Date']).Hours.mean()
```

I want to compute the above figures (total duration, mean duration, etc.) only for the positive 'Hours' numbers in 'frame'. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Sample "frame"

```
import pandas as pd
Line1 = {"Country": "USA", "Date":"01 jan", "Hours":4}
Line2 = {"Country": "USA", "Date":"01 jan", "Hours":3}
Line3 = {"Country": "USA", "Date":"01 jan", "Hours":-999}
Line4 = {"Country": "Japan", "Date":"01 jan", "Hours":3}
pd.DataFrame([Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4])
```

Comment: please provide a sample dataframe and expected result

Comment: "frame" looks like this:
Date, Country, Hours
01/01/2012, USA, 4
01/01/2012, USA, 3
01/01/2012, USA, -999
01/01/2012, Japan, 3

The output "aggregated" should look like this:
Date, Country, Count, Count_positives, Total duration, Mean duration
01/01/2012, USA, 3,2,7,3.5
01/01/2012, Japan, 1,1,3,3

Comment: Note, ``provide a dataframe`` means some valid python code to rebuild it.

Comment: Ok let me try to provide the code for that

Comment: what result you expect if `line4['hours'] = -1`?

Comment: if there are no positive "Hours" for a specific date-country, it should be blank

Comment: What do you mean by blank?  Should there be a `Japan  01 jan   0` or `Japan  01 jan   NaN` row, or should there be no Japan row at all?

Comment: Definitely you should use NaN to mean missing (not -999)

Comment: @DSM, probably NaN is the best solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not as elegant as above, but deals differently some corner cases. `df` stands for `frame` from original question.

```
>>> df.groupby(['Country','Date']).agg(lambda x: x[x>0].mean())
                Hours
Country Date
Japan   01 jan    3.0
USA     01 jan    3.5
>>> df.ix[3, 'Hours'] = -1
>>> df.groupby(['Country','Date']).agg(lambda x: x[x>0].mean())
                Hours
Country Date
Japan   01 jan    NaN
USA     01 jan    3.5
```

Comment: A better approach would be to just use `NaN` as the sentinel value instead of `-999`, and then do no filtering at all and use `nanmean` or other `nan`-insensitive stats functions that have implicit, faster filtering already within them. But I realize you are taking the data as a given from the OP's question.

Comment: One reason to prefer doing the filtering before the groupby is if you're reusing (e.g. sum, count etc.), my guess is will be faster to reuse (though perhaps less clear).

Answer (score 9):

How about -

```
frame[frame["Hours"] > 0].groupby(['Country','Date'])
```

Comment: Far more efficient than using lambda/apply. +1 for this.